# jquery ui datepicker date format

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui

How to convert jquery UI datepicker date format for mysql-phpmyadmin `datetime` type field (default) format?

please help.

Thanks.

Answer (score 21, accepted):

When you are initializing the date time picker, you can pass the format.

```
$( ".selector" ).datepicker({ dateFormat: 'yy-mm-dd' });
```

jQuery UI API Documentation > [Datepicker dateFormat](http://api.jqueryui.com/datepicker/#option-dateFormat)

---

Or after init:

```
//getter
var dateFormat = $( ".selector" ).datepicker( "option", "dateFormat" );
//setter
$( ".selector" ).datepicker( "option", "dateFormat", 'yy-mm-dd' );
```

---

Also according to [MySQL Reference Manual](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/datetime.html):

> MySQL retrieves and displays DATE values in 'YYYY-MM-DD' format.

Comment: what about the time? How do you format to yyyy-mm-dd hh:mm:ss and set the today default?

Answer (score 4):

From the jQuery UI site:

http://jqueryui.com/demos/datepicker/#date-formats

`$(yourInput).datepicker({dateFormat: 'yy-mm-dd'})`