# Jquery datepicker date format

Tags: php, javascript, jquery, mysql, html

How do I get my date to display like this: "yy-mm-dd" inside my date input textbox after I have selected a date?

Information is reading from a database.
So I need it saved in a database again.

JavaScript:

```
<script>
  $(document).ready(function() {
  $("#from").datepicker();
});
</script>
```

Html code:

```
<div class="field">
        <label>Date</label>
       <input type="text" name="date" value="<?php value('date'); ?>" id="from" />   
        <?php if(isset($errors['date'])) { ?>
        <div class="error"><?php echo $errors['date']; ?></div>
        <?php } ?>
 </div>
```

Things that I have tried:

http://docs.jquery.com/UI/Datepicker#option-dateFormat

http://docs.jquery.com/UI/Datepicker/formatDate

[jQuery UI DatePicker - Date Format](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7965371/jquery-ui-datepicker-date-format)

[jquery ui datepicker date format](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6858425/jquery-ui-datepicker-date-format)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Define the format during initialization

```
$("#from").datepicker({
    dateFormat: 'yy-mm-dd'
});
```

The value is updated as well. See an [example](http://jsfiddle.net/Starx/CsdmG/).

Comment: @Dale - you should accept this answer and consider an upvote if it helped you.